# Why does my stylesheet_link_tag return a syntax error in Rails 4?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've followed One Month Rails, The Rails Tutorial, and various other aticles and online sources, am now trying to put together my first app on my own.  It's a simple writing app that lets teachers reflect by answering questions in a few text fields.

I'm trying to import bootstrap into my rails 4 app, and I'm receiving this error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in StaticPages#home
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #2 raised:

Invalid CSS after "": expected selector or at-rule, was "<h1>All posts<h1>"
  (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/stylesheets/posts.css.scss:1)
```

I'm using c9.io for an IDE.

I understand only the basics of the how assets are pre-compiled, so I'll do my best to include the relevant files here.

Here's the code I'm using in my application.html.erb file:

```
    <title>Reflective Teaching</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all',
                                           'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Reflective Teaching</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Posts", posts_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

I think the stylesheets may have something to do with the issue. Here's the application.css.sass file:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

The posts.css.scss file only says:

```
<h1>All posts<h1>
```

The home.html.erb file says:

```
<h1>Reflective Teaching</h1>
<p>Improving student learning by asking three questions:<br>
<ul>
    <li>What worked?</li>
    <li>What didn't?</li>
    <li>What next?</li>
</ul>
</p>
<%= yield 'posts#index' %>
```

From my limited knowledge, I'm not sure if I'm missing a gem that would allow me to link style sheets to my application layout file, or if I've missed some other step in importing bootstrap.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not your ruby it is an issue in your Posts Css file

Comment: can please you post your `home.html.erb` and `posts.css.scss` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html` code should be written in `html file` not in `css file`.
Your `post.css.scss` file contains `html` code `<h1>All posts<h1>` which should be in `html file` and `post.css.scss` should include only `css` not `html` code.

i.e. `posts.css.scss`

```
h1 {
 //css which you want to apply
}
```

[Getting started with Sassy CSS (SCSS)](http://mri.developer.dynamicweb-cms.com/blog/2012/09/getting-started-with-sassy-css-(scss).aspx)

Comment: Deleting the contents of the posts.css.scss file caused the error to disappear.  Thanks very much.  Those are the "big ideas" of programming that I don't always get from reading guides, but learn from talking to experienced programmers.